# Jsoup. Как выбрать методом select

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Есть страничка с таким кодом:

```
<div class="team" style="float: right; background: url('//site.com/img/teams/CPW.jpg?1452774441')"></div>
```

Как я могу вытащить картинку и затем вставить её в GridView?
Вот я попробовал что-то сделать, но думаю это неправильный подход

```
Elements teamPics = doc.select("background|url");
```

Comment: мне кажется, что это невозможно сделать при помощи `select`.

Comment: А что посоветуете?

Comment: выбирать `select`'ом весь стиль, и с помощью регулярных выражений - выдирать background url из стиля уже

Comment: каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> выбирать select'ом весь стиль, и с помощью регулярных выражений -
>   выдирать background url из стиля уже

```
String html = "<div class=\"team\" style=\"float: right; background: url('//site.com/img/teams/CPW.jpg?1452774441')\"></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String slyle = doc.select("div").attr("style"); 

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("url('") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("'"));
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(slyle);
if (matcher.find()) {
    Log.d("TAG", matcher.group(1)); // //site.com/img/teams/CPW.jpg?1452774441
}
```

Comment: А если на странице несколько картинок типа (//site.com/img/teams/*.jpg) то как можно поступить?

Comment: @AlexSuvorov, наверно как то так `for (Element div : doc.select("div")) {
            String slyle = div.attr("style");
            ...
        }`

Comment: блин. элементарно. Я всё к ссылке привязался(